# How do i create an overlay navigation menu?

Tags: jquery

I would like to create something similar to this http://www.domanistudios.com/mobile/

I'm pretty sure I need jquery but I havent been able to find a plugin that could do something similar to this.

edit sorry: I meant the navigation menu. When you click on the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing my answer based on your edit to your question...

Viewing the source code of the site you linked to (specifically in [this](http://www.domanistudios.com/mobile/js/scripts/concat.js) file) shows that the site is using the HTML5 JavaScript API directly in addition to using jQuery for the navigation menu. In other words, it is not using a jQuery plugin that you can easily port elsewhere.

You can use something simple like [Dropit](http://dev7studios.com/dropit/) with a bit of CSS customization for the navigation menu, and add event handlers using the Dropit API (i.e., the "aftershow" and "afterhide" options) to show/hide the other content on the page when the navigation menu is opened/closed.

Comment: here is what i have so far. How do i make the black box reach the full height? trulyamped.com/dropit